# Cutting hole in raster using polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6

I have two layers: a layer with a raster and a layer with a polygon, I need to cut a polygon from a layer with a raster, how to do it?

It is necessary to make a straight hole, and not to create a new layer
not true:

[image]

just like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some info regarding your license? Do you have advanced license or spatial analyst?

Comment: @kowalski I don't know where to look, the cheapest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS, an option is the [Erase tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm)

[image]

There are steps you can follow that I found [clip hole in raster](https://community.esri.com/thread/171975)

Here are the steps... ***(Just swap out your layers accordingly.)***

1. Create a vector polygon of the entire US (including Texas).
2. Use the "Erase" tool to clip out (erase) Texas from the US shapefile. Now you will have a polygon of the US with Texas removed.
3. Use the Extract By Mask tool and have the DEM as your input raster and the new vector shapefile of the US (with Texas erased) as the other input.
4. You will now have a DEM with everything but Texas.

Comment: And unless the erase is not used for a vector layer?

Comment: @user140079, since you already have the vector layer, you can then start from step 3 by using the Extract By Mask tool which will allow you to "cut a hole" in the raster using the polygon feature you have which would need to have the same hole.

Comment: I added a picture that I displays when using the tool